# How should I avoid this memory warning?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, naming-conventions

I have a method that returns a `CGPath` and is generating analyzer warnings. The method is declared in a protocol. Here is an example implementation that is generating the warning:

> "Potential leak of an object allocated on line 47 and stored into 'path'":

```
- (CGPathRef)createPathForBounds:(CGRect)bounds key:(NSString *)key;
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:OvalColumn])
    {
        CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, NULL);
        return path;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Here is example usage that is generating the warning, "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

```
CGPathRef path = [self.delegate createPathForBounds:bounds key:someKey];

// Use the path to do some drawing

CGRelease(path);
```

My memory management is correct; I'm passing back a retained `CGPath` from my protocol method and I'm releasing it in the calling block, so I know the warnings can be ignored, but I'd like to remove them altogether.

Am I missing a naming convention that will make the analyzer happy?
Can functions be defined in protocols?
How will subclassing work?

Comment: Could you perhaps disclose the wording of the warning you're getting, or must we guess?

Comment: What happens if you rename your method to pathForBounds:key: ??

Comment: @T That was the original name. I renamed it to `create…` hoping it would fix the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`- (CGPathRef)newPathForBounds:(CGRect)bounds key:(NSString *)key`

a detailed note on the topic can be found [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html)

alternatively, you could have chosen to use the attribute `cf_returns_retained`, but it's best (imo) to favor naming conventions.

Comment: Beautiful. So obvious in hindsight.

Comment: I don't know why he was down voted. This is absolutely the right answer. The analyzer is working off of method naming conventions. Changing the name to "newPathForBounds" tells the analyzer (and any developer using it) exactly what this method is doing - and that you should expect a retained object to get spit out the other end.

Comment: I just assumed methods returning Foundation objects had to use the Foundation naming conventions. I also don't know why this got a down vote.

Comment: For anyone finding this thread in the future, I'd like to point out two (separate) documents: The Cocoa Naming Conventions - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html (which use "new") and the Core Foundation Naming Conventions - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029 (which use "create").